# Disable drag drop in other columns in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How can I disable drag drop in other columns in datagridview? Like I want to disable drag drop in column 1 and the rest is not disabled. How to achieve this?

This is my code for drag drop:

```
Private CR As Integer, CC As Integer, CV As Object
Private Sub DataGridView1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragDrop
    Dim ClientPoint As Point = DataGridView1.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
    Dim hit As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = DataGridView1.HitTest(ClientPoint.X, ClientPoint.Y)
    CR = hit.RowIndex : If CR < 0 Then Exit Sub
    CC = hit.ColumnIndex : If CC < 0 Then Exit Sub
    DataGridView1.Item(CC, CR).Value = CV
End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_DragOver(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragOver
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseDown
    Dim hit As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
    CR = hit.RowIndex : If CR < 0 Then Exit Sub
    CC = hit.ColumnIndex : If CC < 0 Then Exit Sub
    CV = DataGridView1.Item(CC, CR).Value : If CV Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    DataGridView1.DoDragDrop(CV, DragDropEffects.Move)
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to pickup the column or row # from one of the events. like CellMouseEnter and use the e.columnIndex  to validate or change the drag icon to something else

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: Go to the list of events for your grid and select CellMouseEnter. The same way you did for drag and drop. if e.columnIndex =3 then .....or whatever column you don't or  want to drop on it also use CellmouseLeave to change the icon back when the mouse leave the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have everything you need in order to do what you want, infact you have almost done it already.

The hit test information contains all the information you need. Just modify your code to check the `ColumnIndex` and change the cursor (effect) accordingly:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DragOver(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragOver
    Dim ClientPoint As Point = DataGridView1.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
    Dim hit As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = DataGridView1.HitTest(ClientPoint.X, ClientPoint.Y)

    If hit.ColumnIndex <= 0 Then
        'If we're at the first column (or no column) display a "stop" cursor.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    Else
        'For all other columns display a "move" cursor.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
    End If
End Sub
```

Then, in *both* your `DragDrop` event handler and the `MouseDown` event handler, change this:

```
CC = hit.ColumnIndex : If CC < 0 Then Exit Sub
```

to this:

```
CC = hit.ColumnIndex : If CC <= 0 Then Exit Sub
```

If the column index is zero it means we're on the first column, thus exit the method since we don't want to be able to drag or drop items in it/from it.